# Call to a member function func() on array

Tags: cakephp-1.3

While I am trying to call COALESCE function in query builder it shows the fatal error

> Call to a member function func() on array" .

Here is my code

```
$query = $this->Ticket->find();
$condition = array(
    'AND' => array(
        'Ticket.owner' => $query->func()->COALESCE($owner,'owner'),
        'Ticket.status' => $query->func()->COALESCE($status,'status'),
        'Ticket.updatedTime >=' => $query->func()->COALESCE($dateFrom,'updatedTime'),
        'Ticket.updatedTime <=' => $query->func()->COALESCE($dateTo,'updatedTime')
    )
);


$this->paginate = array(
    'limit' => 10,
    'order' =>'Ticket.updatedTime desc',
    'conditions' => $condition
);
```

Comment: Is it really cake 1.3?

Comment: Yes.It is cakephp 1.3

Comment: in this case you are mixing cakephp1.3 and cake 3 code. There is no query object in cake 1.3. Is there a reason why you are developing in cake 1.3? It is an old and not more maintained version

Comment: Yes..ok I understood.Any other way to call  COALESCE function in cakephp 1.3.It is an old site.Now I have got a small updation in it.